# how to assume a trait is enabled when overriding its attributes in factory-boy

Tags: python, factory-boy

In factory-boy I'm using [a trait](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#traits) to create an optional related object.

```py
class WarehouseToCustomerFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = WarehouseToCustomer
        exclude = ["billing_profile"]


    account = factory.SubFactory(AccountFactory, billing_plan=Account.THREEPL_BILLING_PLAN)    
    warehouse_accepted = True
    customer_accepted = True

    class Params:
        with_billing_profile = factory.Trait(
            billing_profile = factory.SubFactory(
                "factories.billing_profile.BillingProfileFactory",
                account=factory.SelfAttribute("..account"),
                name="Small Customer"
            ),
            billing_profile_id = factory.SelfAttribute("billing_profile.id")
        )
```

So I can create my object without a "billing_profile" by default, but if I explicitly enable the trait, it's created.

```
>>> WarehouseToCustomerFactory(with_billing_profile=True)
```

Overriding attributes if the trait is on also works,

```py
>>> WarehouseToCustomerFactory(with_billing_profile=True, billing_profile__name="Medium Customer")
```

But is it possible to assume `with_billing_profile=True` if I'm explicitly overriding `billing_profile` or any of its attributes? For example...

```py
>>> WarehouseToCustomerFactory(billing_profile=a_profile_instance)
>>> WarehouseToCustomerFactory(billing_profile__name="A custom profile")
```